# How To Write a trigger in postgres to update another column when data inserted into another cloum with same value in same table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Please Find below Table structure:-

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empname  text NOT NULL,
    salary  integer,
    salary1 integer
);
```

Whenever i will insert data into emp table using below query salary1 column should be filled automatically using trigger in postgres ?

```
insert into emp(empname,salary) values('Tarik','1200');
```

I have tried below code,But it is not working for me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee_insert_trigger_fnc()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    update emp set salary1=NEW.salary where NEW.salary=NEW.salary;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

create TRIGGER employee_insert_trigger
AFTER Insert
 ON emp
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE employee_insert_trigger_fnc();
```

Please help..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after my R&D:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee_insert_trigger_fnc()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
        NEW.salary1 := NEW.salary;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

create TRIGGER employee_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
 ON ami_master.emp
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE employee_insert_trigger_fnc();
```